# How to name a file on the server?

Tags: php, filenames, uniqueidentifier

I want to save files (mostly images and docs) on server, but I have a dilemma: How should it will be named? (each file will have record in DB - ID, title, fileName, extension, created, ...)

1. My first idea is that it will be named by ID (from DB - each name will be unique), but when somebody will download it, it will have ugly name (ID)
2. Second idea is that it will be named by original file name, but it's not sure that names will be unique. So each time I upload something, I must check all DB for duplicate names.
3. Last idea is to concatenate ID with name ( fileName_ID) so it will be unique, but I am not really happy with it.

Is there any better solution?

Thanks for answers. Michal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 2 : forget it. It is not sure at all.

Solution 3 can be alright.

Solution 1 is okay.

You just have to change the filename when the user downloads it.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.getFileNameFromDB($file_id));
```

Comment: Is there any way to transform IDname to originalName when you only want to show it on web page (in <img src="..." /> tag), but not download via Save dialog window?

Comment: You don't have access to "Save Dialog" (browser behavior), so you cannot do anything with it. Otherwise, you have apache, mod_rewrite and .htaccess, but it can be a little bit difficult for what you want. You still can try.

Answer (score 4):

> My first idea is that it will be named by ID (from DB - each name will be unique)

This is the right answer.

> but when somebody will download it, it will have ugly name (ID)

That's why we give it a pretty name in the `Content-Disposition` header.

Answer (score 0):

there is another idea use random number and out the random number before the file name

```
$random_digit=rand(0000,9999);

$new_file_name=$random_digit.$file_name;
```

or use your last idea and when download or display rename it without id

Comment: I don't like this idea with random number - there is very small possibility that you already have the same name (in larger counts of files).